# When declaring a function in C++/CLI, what is the meaning of the signs ^ and * before and after a variable?

Tags: function, variables, c++-cli, declaration

For example:

Let's say we have a class called MyClass.

`String^ MyClass::GetSomeInfoForExamplePuprs( int InfoNumber )
{
}`

or

`static String ^GetOtherInfoExample()
{
}`

or

`String ^GetOtherInfoExample(object *Something)
{
}`

I saw it in source code and can't figure it out.

Comment: Is it possible to edit the title to refer to C++/CLI instead of C++? I ask because the managed handle (^) is specific to the C++/CLI and has nothing to do with standard C++.

James McNellis has the correct answer, btw.

Answer (score 25):

The asterisk (`*`) indicates a pointer.

The caret (`^`) is not C++.  It is C++/CLI, and indicates a managed handle (that is, a "pointer" to an object on the managed heap).